# Using git lfs and configuring SSH keys

Tags: git, ssh-keys, git-lfs

I'm starting on a new project. Their repository contains large files >50MB. To properly clone the repo. I've been told I need to use git-lfs. I installed it, and used `git clone`, and then `git lfs install` inside the project folder. Then I used `git lfs fetch`. It returns an error of:

```
batch request: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).: exit status 255
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://github.com/***/***.git/info/lfs'
```

I already have a working ssh key pair, with the ssh key added to github (which is how i'm able to clone a large portion of the files already). The original `git clone` fails when it encounters the first file it hits that is greater than 50MB.

I've searched the git lfs issues page, although I have not posted one. My guess is that the git lfs client cannot find the ssh keypair I have in .ssh. By the way this is on a Windows 10 VM. The host machine is Ubuntu.

Comment: Is your SSH key in standard folder `~/.ssh` with standard name (like `id_rsa`)? Or did you setup git to get it in another location? In the second case it may be necessary to give the location to git lfs too.

Comment: my ssh keys are in C:\Users\<username>\.ssh. The filenames are id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. They work naturally with the normal git command. It feels like the git lfs client is not detecting them, and I don't know why. I also checked the git lfs docs and didn't see anything related to configuring it to point it to a specific key location.

Comment: You can try to execute the command with `GIT_TRACE=1` to debug what calls are made.

Comment: Do you have a passphrase on your SSH key? (https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3216)

Comment: Yes! I regenerated the key and now no longer get the public key error. It seems git clone will work just fine now (perhaps it uses the installed git lfs program automatically).